# ORA-12054 while creating Materialized View

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

Now I am working with Materialized views and i try to create test materialized view:

```
  create table ma_user.test_mview
(
  col1 int,
  col2 int,
  date_col timestamp
)

insert all
  into ma_user.test_mview values (1,1,SYSDATE)
  into ma_user.test_mview values (1,2,SYSDATE + 10/1440)
  into ma_user.test_mview values (1,2,SYSDATE + 30/86400)
  into ma_user.test_mview values (2,1,SYSDATE + 1/48)
  into ma_user.test_mview values (2,2,SYSDATE + 1/24)
  into ma_user.test_mview values (2,2,SYSDATE + 1/72)
  into ma_user.test_mview values (2,3,SYSDATE + 1/96)
  SELECT * FROM dual;

  CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ma_user.test_mat_view1
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH
complete
ON COMMIT
as
  select col1,col2 from ma_user.test_mview
  where current_date > date_col;
```

but I get an error:

> ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the
>   materialized view.

Maybe I should change `ON COMMIT` on `ON_DEMAND`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using current_date function in your query, its not able to issue work. Change it to ON DEMAND. It will work.

Also create a primary key for your table.

The two refresh execution modes are ON COMMIT and ON DEMAND. Depending on the materialized view you create, some of the options may not be available.

ON COMMIT

Refresh occurs automatically when a transaction that modified one of the materialized view's detail tables commits. This can be specified as long as the materialized view is fast refreshable (in other words, not complex). The ON COMMIT privilege is necessary to use this mode.

ON DEMAND

Refresh occurs when a user manually executes one of the available refresh procedures contained in the DBMS_MVIEW package (REFRESH, REFRESH_ALL_MVIEWS, REFRESH_DEPENDENT).

```
Working for me: -


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_mat_view1
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE
ON COMMIT
as
  select col1,col2 from test_mview
 -- where current_date > date_col
  ;
```

Comment: now i deleted where clause from this query, but I get the same error.

Comment: When I use current_date in my MATERIALIZED VIEW, should i refresh this view manually every time when i want to get actual results?

Comment: On commit will provide you result on everytime there is some change in the base table table. No need to manula refresh. When you make it on demand you will have to use some scheduler to get the refreshed data.

Comment: I didn't understand the bit about this situation: if today my clause current_date > date_col returns 10 rows, but tomorrow it will be 15 rows, should i refresh data to get actual results tomorrow? If my memory serves me right, the result of mat.viewes is a permanent data if view wont be refreshed.

Comment: I hope you understand why you tried for COMPLETE refresh. Oracle itself gives 3 types of refreshes to help user to meet their need.  REFRESH [FAST | COMPLETE | FORCE ].. Explore these conditions.

Comment: Her in your case you can choose for FAST refresh rather than complete which wil only bring the lastest records